# Authenticate user inside all virtual servers

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, single-sign-on, jsessionid, virtual-server

I have around 5 virtual servers on **glassfish** and i'm going to authenticate user inside all virtual servers but any virtual server has individual session id.
how can i do this? 
What is a **JSESSIONIDSSO** and will be able it solve my problem?

http://v1.localhost:81 => sessionID=7f60cc7076f690b365d85cff0a45
http://v2.localhost:81 => sessoinID=7b6d35dd17cbb05982ef769a12f7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not expert but you can consider [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/features.html) and [CAS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=66427)

There are similar questions may help you.
[How to implement single sign on across multiple JVM based applications using Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030391/how-to-implement-single-sign-on-across-multiple-jvm-based-applications-using-spr)

[Single Sign On [SSO] across different domains using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121278/single-sign-on-sso-across-different-domains-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

Shiro Session Clustering with Cache can help you out in this scenario. The session will be managed by shiro using the clustered cache.
An example is: 
https://github.com/stormpath/shiro-hazelcast-web-sample